# RTSP VOD Server

Tags: video, rtsp

I need to set up an RTSP VOD server. Which are the suggested servers. I need to stream videos in 3gp format. All are pre recorded videos. Let me know of available free/paid options?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Darwin Streaming Server is free, and support 3gp format.
Real's Helix Streaming Server is paid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another VOD Server... (Written in 100% C#)

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Article on CodeProject @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp